# disabling JavaFX TableView's vertical scrollbar

Tags: javafx, scrollbar, tableview

I'd like to disable vertical scrollbar in a tableview to not be shown when there are too many items in it. 
If it's posibble than my next question is: can i still scroll this table? For example bind scrolling to two buttons - up and down....

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using css:

```
.table-view .scroll-bar:vertical > .increment-button,
.table-view .scroll-bar:vertical > .decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

can help a little as the table still shows a scrollbar(though a very small one)